# How to detect HTML redirection

Tags: safari, macos

I have a script that opens a random pick from a local list of over a thousand URIs on a particular website.  I haven't changed the script, but today, every time, I get a page that is not on the list but is on the same website.  The URI requested is not in my browser history.  (Safari)

Is there a way I can detect a redirection?

`tcpdump` comes to mind, but the output is difficult to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use curl and don't tell it to follow redirects you'll get the 3xx response code back and can use that to see where you're being redirected.

eg.

```
➜  curl -v apple.com
*   Trying 17.253.144.10:80...
*   Trying [2620:149:af0::10]:80...
* Connected to apple.com (17.253.144.10) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: apple.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
< Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2023 00:54:52 GMT
< Connection: close
< Via: http/1.1 usnyc3-edge-bx-011.ts.apple.com (acdn/59.14204)
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Location: https://www.apple.com/
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: none
< CDNUUID: d503e213-6686-4d83-822f-c424b6638655-321701193
< Content-Length: 304
<
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Has Moved</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Document Has Moved</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: The document you requested has moved to a new location.  The new location is "https://www.apple.com/".
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
* Closing connection 0
```

To limit output to just the response code do something like:

```
➜  curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" apple.com
301
➜  curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" https://www.apple.com
200
```

If you're using Python and the requests library you can call status on your request object and get the response code too.

eg. `response.status_code`